# How to query the containing partition of a file with KDE/Qt4?

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

I'm using KDE, and I'm toying with the idea of hacking the code for Dolphin File Manager (and potentially Konqueror if necessary) to get context-sensitive drag and drop behaviour (i.e. files are moved within the same partition, or copied if they're moved across partitions or the source is read only).

To do this, I think I'd need to find out the containing partition of the source and destination (easy enough on Windows using the drive letter, but on Linux, as mount points can be almost anywhere, it can't be reliably derived from the file path), and compare them.
Does anyone know how I can find out the partition that contains a given file?

It must be possible - I know Nautilus provides this sort of behaviour, but I'm not familiar enough with GTK to track down the appropriate section in the source code to see how its done...

Answer (score 3):

Qt doesn't provide API for this. For POSIX, have a look at [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Comment: Helpful answer :-)
Don't suppose you know whether KDE implements this? Not, of course, that I couldn't fish around for that answer myself...

Comment: Unless the KDE function provides more functionality that you need, why not using the standard POSIX one?

Comment: @Koying: I'm uncertain about using native POSIX functions in KDE code, as KDE is ported to other operating systems, and I imagine it would be easier to reimplement KDE functions on another OS than to try to use a function not available on that OS. But these things are, as ever, complex, and I'm not 100% sure on this one. I shall have to ask the KDE devs.

Comment: Koying: kdelibs are ported to Windows, so are many KDE applications.

Answer (score 0):

For KDE, you can use [`KIO::stat()`](http://api.kde.org/4.7-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kio/html/namespaceKIO.html#a6b1b42bc2da7ac24630d530741e1a792) to get mostly the same info as POSIX' `stat` function but asynchronously.

The device id should be in the field `UDS_DEVICE_ID` of the result.

Comment: I don't suppose you know if it's recommended to use this over the native POSIX stat(), say, for portability reasons? (I know there's a windows port of KDE)

Comment: For portability reasons you should stay away from kdelibs, if you only need it for that single function.

Comment: Even if the programs I'm modifying are part of KDE?

Comment: I forgot you were talking about Dolphin... Since Dolphin can display files that are not on the local file systems (ftp, ssh, samba...), you might have to use `KIO::stat` (if it works for those file too).